# Why IQ test "discrete scores" are said to have "Normal shape"

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, measurement-error, measurement, measure-theory

IQ test scores don't increment in decimals, but in whole numbers (e.g., 138, 140, 150 etc.). In other words, ***IQ tests only provide discrete scores [not continuous]*** (No body can get an IQ score of $115.568...$).

If so, how is it that we say that population IQ test scores has a $Normal~Shape$ with  mean of $100$ and sigma of $15$, normality doesn't apply to discrete variables?

More generally in human research, no one uses thermometer-type (precise and graduated) measurement tools, instead they often use measurement tools that produce discrete scores. How assumptions of normality to perform statistical tests such as ***t-test*** can apply then?

Comment: There are, of course, continuous distributions in mathematical statistics. I have never seen continuous data since irrational numbers are difficult to record digitally. Whether some recorded data is well-described by a mathematical model is a matter of judgement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two reasons. First, we assume them to be *approximately* normally distributed. Normal distribution is an approximation in here. It is obviously wrong, but, nonetheless it often nicely fits the data and makes computations easier. Second, we assume that there is underlying latent variable that is continuous that is *measured* on discrete scale and the results are manifested in non-continuous values. Moreover, you *can* have continuous IQ scores if you use some kind of latent variable model, like Item Response Theory models, that makes prediction about true IQ scores on continuous scale based on discrete data.